Updating list in R; accumulating values by multiple groups
I have a folder of csv files which I need to load into the R environment, gather statistics by multiple groups and then update a list, with the end result being accumulated values per group. Here is some dummy data:-
df1<-structure(list(Date = c("01/01/2021", "02/01/2021", "03/01/2021", 
                       "04/01/2021", "05/01/2021", "06/01/2021", "07/01/2021", "08/01/2021", 
                       "09/01/2021", "10/01/2021", "11/01/2021", "12/01/2021", "13/01/2021", 
                       "14/01/2021", "15/01/2021", "16/01/2021", "17/01/2021", "18/01/2021", 
                       "19/01/2021", "20/01/2021", "21/01/2021", "22/01/2021", "23/01/2021", 
                       "01/01/2021", "02/01/2021", "03/01/2021", "04/01/2021", "05/01/2021", 
                       "06/01/2021", "07/01/2021", "08/01/2021", "09/01/2021", "10/01/2021", 
                       "11/01/2021", "12/01/2021", "13/01/2021", "14/01/2021", "01/12/2021", 
                       "02/12/2021", "03/12/2021", "04/12/2021", "05/12/2021", "06/12/2021", 
                       "07/12/2021", "08/12/2021", "09/12/2021", "10/12/2021", "11/12/2021", 
                       "12/12/2021", "13/12/2021", "14/12/2021", "15/12/2021"), ID = c("ABC", 
                                                                                       "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", 
                                                                                       "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", 
                                                                                       "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "DEF", "DEF", "DEF", "DEF", "DEF", 
                                                                                       "DEF", "DEF", "DEF", "DEF", "DEF", "DEF", "DEF", "DEF", "DEF", 
                                                                                       "GHI", "GHI", "GHI", "GHI", "GHI", "GHI", "GHI", "GHI", "GHI", 
                                                                                       "GHI", "GHI", "GHI", "GHI", "GHI", "GHI"), Type = c("Type1", 
                                                                                                                                           "Type2", "Type1", "Type1", "Type1", "Type1", "Type1", "Type2", 
                                                                                                                                           "Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", "Type1", 
                                                                                                                                           "Type2", "Type1", "Type1", "Type1", "Type1", "Type2", "Type1", 
                                                                                                                                           "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type1", "Type1", "Type1", 
                                                                                                                                           "Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", "Type1", 
                                                                                                                                           "Type2", "Type1", "Type1", "Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", 
                                                                                                                                           "Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type1", "Type1", "Type1", "Type1", 
                                                                                                                                           "Type1", "Type2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -52L
                                                                                                                                           ))

df2<-structure(list(Date = c("01/04/2022", "02/04/2022", "03/04/2022", 
                        "04/04/2022", "05/04/2022", "06/04/2022", "01/07/2022", "02/07/2022", 
                        "03/07/2022", "04/07/2022", "05/07/2022", "01/12/2022", "02/12/2022", 
                        "03/12/2022", "04/12/2022", "05/12/2022", "06/12/2022", "07/12/2022", 
                        "08/12/2022", "09/12/2022", "10/12/2022", "01/02/2022", "02/02/2022", 
                        "03/02/2022", "04/02/2022", "05/02/2022", "06/02/2022", "07/02/2022", 
                        "08/02/2022", "09/02/2022", "10/02/2022", "01/04/2022", "02/04/2022", 
                        "03/04/2022", "04/04/2022", "05/04/2022", "06/04/2022", "07/04/2022", 
                        "08/04/2022", "09/04/2022", "10/04/2022", "11/04/2022", "12/04/2022", 
                        "13/04/2022", "14/04/2022", "15/04/2022", "16/04/2022", "17/04/2022", 
                        "18/04/2022", "19/04/2022", "20/04/2022", "21/04/2022", "22/04/2022", 
                        "23/04/2022", "24/04/2022", "25/04/2022", "26/04/2022", "27/04/2022", 
                        "28/04/2022", "29/04/2022", "30/04/2022", "01/05/2022", "02/05/2022", 
                        "03/05/2022", "04/05/2022", "05/05/2022", "06/05/2022", "07/05/2022", 
                        "08/05/2022", "09/05/2022", "10/05/2022", "11/05/2022", "12/05/2022", 
                        "13/05/2022", "14/05/2022", "15/05/2022", "16/05/2022", "17/05/2022", 
                        "18/05/2022", "19/05/2022", "20/05/2022", "21/05/2022", "22/05/2022", 
                        "23/05/2022", "24/05/2022"), ID = c("ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", 
                                                            "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", 
                                                            "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "HIJ", 
                                                            "HIJ", "HIJ", "HIJ", "HIJ", "HIJ", "HIJ", "HIJ", "HIJ", "HIJ", 
                                                            "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", 
                                                            "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", 
                                                            "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", 
                                                            "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", 
                                                            "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", 
                                                            "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN", "LMN"
                        ), Type = c("Type2", "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", 
                                    "Type2", "Type2", "Type2", "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", "Type1", 
                                    "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", "Type2", 
                                    "Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", "Type2", "Type2", "Type1", 
                                    "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", 
                                    "Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", "Type1", 
                                    "Type2", "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", "Type1", 
                                    "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", 
                                    "Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", "Type1", 
                                    "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", 
                                    "Type1", "Type2", "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", "Type2", "Type1", 
                                    "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", "Type2", "Type1", 
                                    "Type2", "Type1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -85L
                                    ))

df3<-structure(list(Date = c("01/01/2021", "02/01/2021", "03/01/2021", 
                        "04/01/2021", "05/01/2021", "06/01/2021", "07/01/2021", "08/01/2021", 
                        "09/01/2021", "01/07/2023", "02/07/2023", "03/07/2023", "04/07/2023", 
                        "05/07/2023", "06/07/2023", "07/07/2023", "08/07/2023", "09/07/2023", 
                        "10/07/2023", "11/07/2023", "12/07/2023", "13/07/2023"), ID = c("ABC", 
                                                                                        "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "HIJ", 
                                                                                        "HIJ", "HIJ", "HIJ", "HIJ", "HIJ", "HIJ", "HIJ", "HIJ", "HIJ", 
                                                                                        "HIJ", "HIJ", "HIJ"), Type = c("Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type1", 
                                                                                                                       "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type1", 
                                                                                                                       "Type1", "Type1", "Type1", "Type1", "Type1", "Type1", "Type2", 
                                                                                                                       "Type2", "Type2", "Type2", "Type2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 -22L))




write.csv(df1, file="df1.csv")
write.csv(df2, file="df2.csv")
write.csv(df3, file="df3.csv")




I have a list created where I want to store some outputs of a group-by analysis of each csv file that I load in:-


#creating sequence of month and years
start_date <- as.Date("2021-01-01")
end_date <- as.Date("2023-12-31")
date_sequence <- seq.Date(from = start_date, to = end_date, by = "1 months")
formatted_dates <- format(date_sequence, "%Y-%m")
formatted_dates


#creating a unique identifier
unique_id<-c("ABC","DEF","GHI","HIJ","LMN")




#creating a list to store results in

month_year_list<-list()


for (i in unique_id) {
  
  counts_month_year<-data.frame(Month_Yr = c(formatted_dates),
                                Type1 = c(NA),
                                Type2 = c(NA))
  
  month_year_list[[i]]<-counts_month_year
}


Lastly, here is the code I am working with:-
#saving the file names to an object in order to load in
all_files = list.files(pattern = ".csv")



for (i in all_files) {
  
  df<-read_csv(i)#loading in csv
  #getting grouped counts
  grouped_analysis<-df%>%
    mutate(new_date=dmy(Date), Month_Yr=as.factor(substr(new_date,1,7)))%>%
    group_by(ID,Month_Yr,Type)%>%
    count(Month_Yr,Type, .drop=FALSE)%>%
    spread(Type,n)
  
  #removing NA column and replacing NA's with zeroes
  grouped_analysis$`<NA>`<-NULL
  grouped_analysis$Type1[is.na(grouped_analysis$Type1)]<-0
  grouped_analysis$Type2[is.na(grouped_analysis$Type2)]<-0
  
  
  ind <- match(grouped_analysis$ID, unique_id)#matching ID
  
  
  #inner for loop
  
  for (j in ind) {
    
    df_id<-month_year_list[[j]]
    
    df_update <- grouped_analysis[grouped_analysis$ID == unique_id[j],]
    
    month_year_list[[j]] <- df_id%>%
      left_join(df_update, by = "Month_Yr")%>%
      mutate(Type1 = coalesce(Type1.x + Type1.y, Type1.x, Type1.y),
             Type2 = coalesce(Type2.x + Type2.y, Type2.x, Type2.y))%>%
      select(Month_Yr, Type1, Type2)
    
  }#gathering grouped counts and updating the list
}

I want to be able to add the values from each iteration of the grouped analysis onto the values which pre-exist in the list. However, whenever I do this with the current code, the values artificially inflate in some instances.
For instance, ID "ABC" appears in all three csv files and has the following counts:-
# table(df1$ID,df1$Type)
# 
# Type1 Type2
# ABC    15     8
# DEF     9     5
# GHI    11     4
# > table(df2$ID,df2$Type)
# 
# Type1 Type2
# ABC     7    14
# HIJ     4     6
# LMN    25    29
# > table(df3$ID,df3$Type)
# 
# Type1 Type2
# ABC     5     4
# HIJ     8     5

So in total, ABC should have 27 for Type1 and 26 for Type2 (spread over the Month_Yr variable).
But when I assign the values to the list, the values are artificially inflated.
How may I fix this so that the accumulated values by ID and Month_Yr are correct? Is there an accurate and more efficient way to achieve what I am after?
R Version 3.6.1 "Action of the Toes"
EDIT
Just to clarify, I want to be able to load in each CSV file, group by ID and Month_Yr and count number of observations as demonstrated in my code. I want to add these values to the list by ID. I want to repeat the process for each CSV file, but after the first file, I want to add together the values that already exist in the list with those in the group by analysis.

library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- map(set_names(all_files), read.csv) |>
  bind_rows(.id = "file") |>
  mutate(Month_Yr = format(dmy(Date), "%Y-%m")) |>
  count(ID, Type, Month_Yr) 


updated_month_year_list <- imap(split(df, ~ ID), \(d, nm) {
  month_year_list[[nm]] |>
    pivot_longer(starts_with("Type"), names_to = "Type", values_to = "Total") |>
    left_join(select(d, -ID), by = join_by(Month_Yr, Type)) |>
    mutate(Total = rowSums(pick(n, Total), na.rm = TRUE), .keep = "unused") |>
    pivot_wider(names_from = "Type", values_from = "Total")
})

How it works
You can start by creating a stacked data frame from all the CSV files and then summarizing:
df <- map(set_names(all_files), read.csv) |>
  bind_rows(.id = "file") |>
  mutate(Month_Yr = format(dmy(Date), "%Y-%m")) |>
  count(ID, Type, Month_Yr) 
#     ID  Type Month_Yr  n
# 1  ABC Type1  2021-01 20
# 2  ABC Type1  2022-04  2
# 3  ABC Type1  2022-07  1
# 4  ABC Type1  2022-12  4
# ...

If you sum this across Month_Yr you get the counts you were expecting:
summarize(df, n = sum(n), .by = c(ID, Type))
#     ID  Type  n
# 1  ABC Type1 27
# 2  ABC Type2 26
# 3  DEF Type1  9
# 4  DEF Type2  5
# 5  GHI Type1 11
# 6  GHI Type2  4
# 7  HIJ Type1 12
# 8  HIJ Type2 11
# 9  LMN Type1 25
# 10 LMN Type2 29

The next thing you need to do is update your month_year_list object. You can do this by:

Splitting the above data frame into a named list of data frames
Using the names from the named list to access the correct element of month_year_list and merge your new counts by adding them to those that already exist.
Since df is already in long format and it is easier to process this in long format the elements of month_year_list are converted to a long format for the computation and then pivoted to a wide format for output.

updated_month_year_list <- imap(split(df, ~ ID), \(d, nm) {
  month_year_list[[nm]] |>
    pivot_longer(starts_with("Type"), names_to = "Type", values_to = "Total") |>
    left_join(select(d, -ID), by = join_by(Month_Yr, Type)) |>
    mutate(Total = rowSums(pick(n, Total), na.rm = TRUE), .keep = "unused") |>
    pivot_wider(names_from = "Type", values_from = "Total")
})

Output
updated_month_year_list[1:2] # only showing the first two elements

# $ABC
# A tibble: 36 × 3
#    Month_Yr Type1 Type2
#    <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 2021-01     20    12
#  2 2021-02      0     0
#  3 2021-03      0     0
#  4 2021-04      0     0
#  5 2021-05      0     0
#  6 2021-06      0     0
#  7 2021-07      0     0
#  8 2021-08      0     0
#  9 2021-09      0     0
# 10 2021-10      0     0
# ℹ 26 more rows
# 
# $DEF
# A tibble: 36 × 3
#    Month_Yr Type1 Type2
#    <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 2021-01      9     5
#  2 2021-02      0     0
#  3 2021-03      0     0
#  4 2021-04      0     0
#  5 2021-05      0     0
#  6 2021-06      0     0
#  7 2021-07      0     0
#  8 2021-08      0     0
#  9 2021-09      0     0
# 10 2021-10      0     0
# ℹ 26 more rows


However, rather than create month_year_list it is just easier to use the df data frame directly to create your list.

Sum across files using summarize
Pivot the data to the wide format you are expecting
Split that data frame by ID into a list

df |> 
  summarize(n = sum(n), .by = c(ID, Type, Month_Yr)) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Type", values_from = "n") |>
  split(~ ID)

If you need to have all dates available for every list element that is easy to implement.

I think it could be a bit simpler:
library(readr)
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

summarize_csv <- function(csv) {
  read_csv(csv, col_types = cols(Date = col_date(format = "%d/%m/%Y")),
           col_select = c(Date, ID, Type)) %>% 
    select(ID, Date, Type) %>% 
    mutate(ym = as.yearmon(Date, "%y-%m")) %>% 
    summarise(.by = c(ID, ym, Type), n = n()) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = Type, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))
}

results <- structure(
  list(ID = character(0), 
       ym = structure(numeric(0), class = "yearmon"), 
       Type1 = integer(0), 
       Type2 = integer(0)
  ), 
  row.names = integer(0), 
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

csvs <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$")

for (csv in csvs) {
  csv_data <- summarize_csv(csv)
  # print(csv_data)
  results <- rbind(results, csv_data) %>%  
    arrange(ID, ym) %>%
    summarise(.by = c(ID, ym), Type1 = sum(Type1), Type2 = sum(Type2))
}

print(results)

that gives
# A tibble: 10 × 4
   ID    ym        Type1 Type2
   <chr> <yearmon> <int> <int>
 1 ABC   Jan 2021     20    12
 2 ABC   Apr 2022      2     4
 3 ABC   Jul 2022      1     4
 4 ABC   Dec 2022      4     6
 5 DEF   Jan 2021      9     5
 6 GHI   Dec 2021     11     4
 7 HIJ   Feb 2022      4     6
 8 HIJ   Jul 2023      8     5
 9 LMN   Apr 2022     14    16
10 LMN   May 2022     11    13
                 


# df_list = lapply(list.files(pattern=".csv$"), read.csv) # or similar 
df_list = list(df1, df2, df3)

Note. It is not clear to me whether you want to remove/ignore or keep "duplicated" entries, e.g. compare
X = Reduce(\(...) merge(..., all=TRUE), df_list) |>
  transform(Date = format(as.Date(Date, "%d/%m/%Y"), "%b_%Y")) |>
  with(ftable(ID, Date, Type)) |> as.data.frame() |> sort_by(~ID+Date)
(X = X[X$Freq != 0L, ])

to
Y = do.call(rbind, df_list) |>
  transform(Date = format(as.Date(Date, "%d/%m/%Y"), "%b_%Y")) |>
  with(ftable(ID, Date, Type)) |> as.data.frame() |> sort_by(~ID+Date)
(Y = Y[Y$Freq != 0L, ])

i.e.
> X$Freq - Y$Freq
 [1]  0  0  0  0 -4 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0  0  0  0

However, I think you are looking for
# create tables for each df
tables = lapply(df_list, \(x) {
  transform(x, Date = format(as.Date(Date, "%d/%m/%Y"), "%b_%Y")) |>
    with(ftable(ID, Date, Type)) |> as.data.frame() })
# create dummy table 
blank = do.call(rbind, tables)
blank$Freq = 0L
blank = blank[!duplicated(blank), ]
# combine 
result = Reduce(\(...) merge(..., by=c("ID", "Date", "Type"), all.x=TRUE), 
                     c(list(blank), tables)) |> sort_by(~ID+Date)
# calculate cumulative sums, rename 
result[is.na(result)] = 0L
result[i] = t(apply(result[i<-grepl("Freq", colnames(result))], 1L, cumsum))
names(result)[i] = paste0("df", seq(length(df_list)+1L)-1L)

which results in
> result
    ID     Date  Type df0 df1 df2 df3
1  ABC Dec_2021 Type1   0   0   0   0
2  ABC Dec_2021 Type2   0   0   0   0
3  ABC Jan_2021 Type1   0  15  15  20
4  ABC Jan_2021 Type2   0   8   8  12
5  ABC Apr_2022 Type1   0   0   2   2
6  ABC Apr_2022 Type2   0   0   4   4
7  ABC Dec_2022 Type1   0   0   4   4
8  ABC Dec_2022 Type2   0   0   6   6
9  ABC Feb_2022 Type1   0   0   0   0
10 ABC Feb_2022 Type2   0   0   0   0
11 ABC Jul_2022 Type1   0   0   1   1
12 ABC Jul_2022 Type2   0   0   4   4
13 ABC May_2022 Type1   0   0   0   0
14 ABC May_2022 Type2   0   0   0   0
15 ABC Jul_2023 Type1   0   0   0   0
16 ABC Jul_2023 Type2   0   0   0   0
17 DEF Dec_2021 Type1   0   0   0   0
18 DEF Dec_2021 Type2   0   0   0   0
19 DEF Jan_2021 Type1   0   9   9   9
20 DEF Jan_2021 Type2   0   5   5   5
21 GHI Dec_2021 Type1   0  11  11  11
22 GHI Dec_2021 Type2   0   4   4   4
23 GHI Jan_2021 Type1   0   0   0   0
24 GHI Jan_2021 Type2   0   0   0   0
25 HIJ Jan_2021 Type1   0   0   0   0
26 HIJ Jan_2021 Type2   0   0   0   0
27 HIJ Apr_2022 Type1   0   0   0   0
28 HIJ Apr_2022 Type2   0   0   0   0
29 HIJ Dec_2022 Type1   0   0   0   0
30 HIJ Dec_2022 Type2   0   0   0   0
31 HIJ Feb_2022 Type1   0   0   4   4
32 HIJ Feb_2022 Type2   0   0   6   6
33 HIJ Jul_2022 Type1   0   0   0   0
34 HIJ Jul_2022 Type2   0   0   0   0
35 HIJ May_2022 Type1   0   0   0   0
36 HIJ May_2022 Type2   0   0   0   0
37 HIJ Jul_2023 Type1   0   0   0   8
38 HIJ Jul_2023 Type2   0   0   0   5
39 LMN Apr_2022 Type1   0   0  14  14
40 LMN Apr_2022 Type2   0   0  16  16
41 LMN Dec_2022 Type1   0   0   0   0
42 LMN Dec_2022 Type2   0   0   0   0
43 LMN Feb_2022 Type1   0   0   0   0
44 LMN Feb_2022 Type2   0   0   0   0
45 LMN Jul_2022 Type1   0   0   0   0
46 LMN Jul_2022 Type2   0   0   0   0
47 LMN May_2022 Type1   0   0  11  11
48 LMN May_2022 Type2   0   0  13  13

where column df0 represents the dummy table column to fill, and df1, df2, df3 the cumulative sums; iterative updates:
df0 + df1, df0 + df1 + df2, df0 + df1 + df2 + df3. Notice that this procedure depens on the order of df_list.

Edit
Reshaped this answer which I have given earlier as it seems you want this. Although, you stated something very different:

Sorry but the solution does not address my needs. As I have mentioned in the original post, there is an element of loading in one CSV at a time, gathering the relevant stats by group and accumulating and updating the list accordingly.

and

I want to add these values to the list by ID. I want to repeat the process for each CSV file, but after the first file, I want to add together the values that already exist in the list with those in the group by analysis.

list(df1, df2, df3) |> 
  do.call(what=rbind) |>
  transform(Date=format(as.Date(Date, "%d/%m/%Y"), "%b_%Y")) |>
  with(ftable(ID, Date, Type)) |> as.data.frame() |>
  { \(.) split(.[.$Freq!=0L, ], ~ID) }() |> # cosmetics
  lapply(sort_by, ~Date) # cosmetics

gives
$ABC
    ID     Date  Type Freq
1  ABC Apr_2022 Type1    2
41 ABC Apr_2022 Type2    4
11 ABC Dec_2022 Type1    4
51 ABC Dec_2022 Type2    6
21 ABC Jan_2021 Type1   20
61 ABC Jan_2021 Type2   12
26 ABC Jul_2022 Type1    1
66 ABC Jul_2022 Type2    4

$DEF
    ID     Date  Type Freq
22 DEF Jan_2021 Type1    9
62 DEF Jan_2021 Type2    5

$GHI
    ID     Date  Type Freq
8  GHI Dec_2021 Type1   11
48 GHI Dec_2021 Type2    4

$HIJ
    ID     Date  Type Freq
19 HIJ Feb_2022 Type1    4
59 HIJ Feb_2022 Type2    6
34 HIJ Jul_2023 Type1    8
74 HIJ Jul_2023 Type2    5

$LMN
    ID     Date  Type Freq
5  LMN Apr_2022 Type1   14
45 LMN Apr_2022 Type2   16
40 LMN May_2022 Type1   11
80 LMN May_2022 Type2   13


Thank you for this. I would like a solution that accounts for date if possible.

Then explain the rule.

How may I fix this so that the accumulated values by ID and Month_Yr are correct? Is there an accurate and more efficient way to achieve what I am after?

Please have a look on the EDIT.

Sorry but the solution does not address my needs. As I have mentioned in the original post, there is an element of loading in one CSV at a time, gathering the relevant stats by group and accumulating and updating the list accordingly.
